# Drupal: Module output not appearing on front end

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to create a Drupal module. I've been able to setup the configuration form on the admin section - it runs fine: I can add the component and set configurations and save.

However, nothing appears on the front end of the site. There are no errors. I'm not sure why and, as I am new to Drupal, I'm not sure where to look.

My hook_theme in my .module file looks like:

```
function gallery_grid_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'gallery_grid' => array(
      'template' => 'gallery-grid',
      'path' => 'plugins/content_types/gallery_grid/templates',
      'type' => 'theme',
      'variables' => [],
    )
  );
}
```

The `.tpl` file is intact and has no markup errors.

Would anyone know what file I should be looking at?

EDIT:

I've tried clearing the cache and rebuilding the registry as well as disabling and re-enabling the module, to no affect.

The module is added to a page panel as a component (gear icon, Add Content).

Comment: Try clearing the cache and redo the operation.
If problem not solved. Try printing something on the module page and see if it appears or not.

Comment: @RonySamuel sorry, should have mentioned I had tried that.

Comment: How are you expecting it to appear on the front end? Does your module provide a block? Does your module provide a custom page (hook_menu)? Simply providing a hook_theme function does not add any output.

Comment: @2pha I'll add more info above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reasons this needed an absolute path:

```
'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'gallery_grid') . '/plugins/content_types/gallery_grid/templates',
```